# Fantasy novel featuring anti-heroine wood-elf thief famed for ability in bed

Tags: story-identification, elves

I'm trying to remember the title and author of a story featuring a heroine who was almost an anti-heroine.

She was a wood-elf thief who was famed for her ability in bed. It didn't go into graphic detail, but the heroine would occasionally indulge her appetites shamelessly and exhaust some poor guy before heading merrily on her way. She was also connected with an assassin who had been linked to a demon dagger.

Comment: When did you read it, and (if you remember) was it new at the time? Was it in English, was it a translation? What background did this wood-elf evoke (classical fairies, Tolkien, Dungeons and Dragons, Warhammer, …)?

Answer (score 11):

It's from a series of books by [Anne Logston](http://www.logstonslair.com/index2.htm) called [*Shadow*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159426161X), [*Shadow Hunt*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1594261644) and [*Shadow Dance*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0441759904).

> Never trust an elf, a thief, or a woman. Shadow is all three...
> Shadow, a light-hearted (and light-fingered) elven thief, returns to
> her homeland after several centuries' absence only to find that a
> great human trade city has grown up next to the forest in which she
> was born. Now the elves and the humans maintain an uneasy alliance,
> but when Shadow steals a magical bracelet, she finds herself caught in
> the middle of a plot that may tear the city-and the alliance-apart
> forever.

*Shadow Hunt* has the storyline with an assassin called Blade.

> She's a master thief as elusive as her name whose dagger is as sharp as her eyes and wits. Where there's a rich merchant to rob, good food and wine to be had, or a lusty fellow to kiss ... there's Shadow. What do the Guild of Thieves, the deadliest assassin in Allanmere, a long-vanished mage, a treacherous swamp, and a gem missing from a temple have in common? Shadow, of course. When Shadow is accused of a theft of guild-wrecking proportions, she forms an unlikely alliance with the strange immortal creature known only as Blade to find out who has framed her and the Guild of Thieves for the theft-and why. Deadly Companion! When shadow has to recover a stolen jewel from the wizard Baloran, her journey is as perilous as her destination. For only Blade can guide Shadow to the sorcerer's lair ... and Blade is an assassin who takes a life as easily as she takes a breath. Shadow's score with Baloran can end only in destruction. But in the final battle, will Blade be at Shadow's side-or in her way?